# $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}V(\mathbf{x}(t)) = 0$ implies $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{0}$

Tags: real-analysis

(* Note: Originally $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is only open, boundedness is added through later discussion. Further discussion changes $D$ to be compact.)

$D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. Let $\mathbf{x}:[0, \infty) \rightarrow D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous, let $V:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.
Suppose $V(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ if and only if $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, then $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}V(\mathbf{x}(t)) = 0$ implies $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{0}$.

I think this statement holds true to me intuitively, but I am having trouble rigorously show it using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $D$ compact? (I can't see any other way to save it)

Comment: I just did what you suggested. Hope that would make the statement a bit more clear to newcomers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbf{x}(t)\neq 0$, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and sequence $(t_n)_n\subset[0,\infty)$ with $t_n\to\infty$ such that $\lVert\mathbf{x}(t_n)\rVert\geq\varepsilon$. If $D$ is compact (as Brian Moehring suggests) then the sequence $(\mathbf{x}(t_n))_n$ is bounded, hence it has a convergent subsequence $\mathbf{x}(t_{n_k})\to x\in D$, and $x\neq 0$ by the above fact ($\lVert\mathbf{x}(t_n)\rVert\geq\varepsilon$). Therefore, by continuity of $V$, we have that $V(\mathbf{x}(t_{n_k}))\to V(x)\neq 0$ as $k\to\infty$, which contradicts the fact that $V(\mathbf{x}(t))\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

However, if $D$ is not compact, the result you mention does not hold anymore. Take the following example: let $V$ be a continuous function defined on $D=\mathbb{R}^n$, only vanishing at $0$, with $\lim_{\lVert{\mathbf{x}}\rVert\to\infty}V(\mathbf{x})=0$. Take $\mathbf{x}(t)=(t,0,\ldots,0)$. We have that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbf{x}(t)\neq 0$, but $\lim_{t\to\infty}V(\mathbf{x}(t))=0$.

Comment: Is compactness a must-have? In the answer, you used boundedness of $D$ to show the sequence $(\mathbf{x}(t_n))_n$ is bounded. Then I believe you used Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to show the existence of a convergent subsequence $(\mathbf{x}(t_{n_k}))_k$? I think only bounedness of $D$ is utilized here.

Comment: @DerekPan Now that I read the question again, I see that $V$ is defined on D. Note that it was key that $x\in D$ in my argument. If $D$ is not compact (even if it is bounded but not closed), it could happen that $V(\mathbf{x})\to 0$ as $\mathbf{x}\to x\notin D$ and $V$ still vanish only at $0$. In this case, we could take $\mathbf{x}(t)\to x$ as $t\to\infty$ and hence $V(\mathbf{x}(t))\to 0$.

Comment: So closeness of $D$ is needed to make sure the limit value $\mathbf{x}$ stays within $D$. Otherwise, $V(\mathbf{x})$ would be meaningless, since $\mathbf{x}$ could be out of domain? If I understood correctly, I think it makes sense. So after all, $D$ still needs to be compact.

Comment: @DerekPan Yes. There is *little* way out.

Comment: I agree. Again, thank you for the help and the careful observation. I appreciate it a lot.